# Xamarin - An Alternative for ParentView which is now obsolete

Tags: c#, listview, binding, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

I am creating a custom `DataTemplate` that trigger an event in it's parent listview. Here is one trigger:

```
public void OnItemActivated()
{
    ParentView.OnItemActivated(this);
}
```

*'Element.ParentView' is obsolete: 'ParentView is obsolete as of version 2.1.0. Please use Parent instead.* - Says Xamarin

[image: Class types]

In the above image you can see that `Parent` and `ParentView` are diferents and `ParentView` return the `object` I need. I would try to use `Parent.Parent` which work in this case ... Will that always work ? Will that hierarchical structure be always the same ?

So I need the best way to get the `listview` that own the "active" `item`

Perhaps someone could advice me if the `listview` should be listening to his children or should wait for them to talk to him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally understood why `ParentView` is obsolete. The Xamarin page "Document Structure" is not just made by **Views**, but **Elements**.

As a parent of a view may not be a view, `ParentView` become useless.

**My Solution**

I use `(this.Parent as Xamarin.Forms.View)` to get my `ParentView`, my *Parent as View* :)

**Note**

As I said `Parent` is an `Element` which sometime is `View`. So my solution will crash when the Parent is not a View (Why `ParentView` is Obsolete)